# Compiled files not getting fingerprint rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have a number of environments where I deploy an application. In two of them I deploy the following configuration for assets:

```
config.assets.enabled    = true
config.assets.compress   = false
config.assets.compile    = true
config.assets.precompile = false
config.assets.digest     = true
config.assets.debug      = false
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

My applicaton.js, that compiles a number of .js files on it, is not getting a fingerprint, so I don't serve changes to customers that have already cached it.

The web page then serves all assets precompiled with fingerprint except `application.js`

Where can I start to look for this failure?

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is the following option :

`config.assets.compile = true`

It will live compile each file without fingerprint and serve them straight for rails

You should set it to false and use `config.assets.precompile` which should contain the list of all precompiled filed :

`config.assets.precompile += %w(application.js foo.js)`

Then don't forget to run `rake assets:precompile` in your deployment task to recompile new assets.

On a side note, you should also set `config.serve_static_assets` to false and let nginx / apache / your web server handle it for you, serving assets from rails has a big overhead.

Comment: I'm not worrying much about performance at this stage. My point is, every other asset is getting precompiled, but the application.js not.